# how to add if this cell = 0 skip and go next

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I have something thatll auto produce things for me but i want if this cell is = 0 after running select acct then skip and dont produce

```
Sub AutoMakeInv()

    Dim lPrefix As Long
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim Account_Number As String

    For lPrefix = 1 To 14
        For lCount = 1 To 2000
            Account_Number = "F" & Format(lPrefix, "00") & " " & Format(lCount, "0000")
            Debug.Print Account_Number
            Cells(8, 5).Value = Account_Number
            Call SelectAcct
            Call ProduceInv
            ' Do something ...
        
        Next lCount
    Next lPrefix

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like the "If cell = 0" portion may need to be on the SelectAcct or ProduceInv Sub and not this AutoMakeInv. In this one you are not looping through any cells.

Comment: I would guess `SelectAcct` should be a Function not a Sub so the returned value can be used in an IF block. `n = SelectAcct: If n <> 0 then Call ProduceInv`.

Comment: `If` which `Cell = 0` ?

Answer (score 0):

This will check if a cell is 0 and only run your two other subs if it is not:

```
Option Explicit
Sub AutoMakeInv()

    Dim lPrefix As Long
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim Account_Number As String

    For lPrefix = 1 To 14
        For lCount = 1 To 2000
            Account_Number = "F" & Format(lPrefix, "00") & " " & Format(lCount, "0000")
            Debug.Print Account_Number
            Cells(8, 5).Value = Account_Number
            If Not Range("INSERT YOUR CELL ADDRESS").Value = 0 Then
                Call SelectAcct
                Call ProduceInv
            End If
        Next lCount
    Next lPrefix

End Sub
```